# Create Postgres function in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, postgresql, psycopg2, postgresql-9.3

I am creating trying to create a function inside Postgres from Python. My connection to postgres database uses Psycopg 2 and connects successfully in other instances. Code:

```
pg_cursor.execute('CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION %s.fix_geometry(geometry) \
    RETURNS SETOF geometry AS\
    $BODY$\
        SELECT geom the_geom\
        FROM \
                (\
                SELECT (st_dump(st_buffer(st_snaptogrid(st_makevalid(the_geom), 0.5), 0))).geom\
                FROM (SELECT geom the_geom FROM st_dump(st_snaptogrid($1, 0.5))) a\
                ) b\
        WHERE geometrytype(geom) = \'POLYGON\' AND st_area(geom) >= 0.01;\

    $BODY$\
       LANGUAGE sql VOLATILE\
       COST 100\
       ROWS 1000;' %(schema)) #line 84

pg_connection.commit()
pg_cursor.execute('ALTER FUNCTION %s.fix_geometry(geometry) OWNER TO analysis' % (schema))
pg_connection.commit()
```

I get an error:

> line 84, in 
>       ROWS 1000;' %(schema))
>   ProgrammingError: type geometry does not exist

When I run the code in pgAdmin it executes successfully. What am I missing?

Python 2.7, Postgres 9.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the error was just outside of the provided code snippet. Postgre has the geometry type inside of the public schema and when I defined the search path for this code, I only defined the schema in which I was working; public was not included. So....

```
pg_cursor.execute('set search_path =  %s, public' % (schema))
pg_connection.commit()
```